# Posting to Slack channels with bot access token

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have visited https://api.slack.com/apps/APP_ID/oauth and updated the scopes to include `files:write:user`, clicked *Save Changes* and reinstalled my app to ensure the scope changes take effect.

I do the following to post to a channel that my bot is a member of:

```
web.files
  .upload({
    filename,
    file: fs.createReadStream(filename),
    channels: ['{CHANNEL_ID}']
  })
```

However, I still get the following error message:

```
{ ok: false,
  error: 'invalid_channel',
  channel: '["{CHANNEL_ID}"]',
  scopes: [ 'identify', 'bot:basic' ],
  acceptedScopes: [ 'files:write:user', 'post' ] } }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was that I was using an *array* of channel IDs, rather than [what the library expects](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload#arguments) which is a string containing a:

> Comma-separated list of channel names or IDs

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it was because the Bot User wasn't invited to the channel yet. Adding them to the private Slack channel fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `invalid_channel` is not related to scopes, but simply means that Slack does not recognize one of the channels you provided with your API call.

The official documentation says:

> `invalid_channel`: One or more channels supplied are invalid

So you may want to double check that you got the correct channel ID.

Source: https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload#errors

Comment: I grabbed the channel ID from the result of a [channels.list request](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.list) using the same token. It expects the id that starts with a letter `C`, i.e. `channels: ['CXXXXXXXX']`, right?